# How can I get a "clean" list from mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I execute a find query of mongoose:

```
UG.find({ "emailUser": req.body.emailUser }, "nameGroup" ,function (err, groups) {
    console.log(groups)
});
```

The result is "dirty" with some id,

How can I "clean" the result to a simple array -of only "namegroup"?

Answer (score 0):

`id` is always returned by mongodb. You need to explicitly exclude it.

```
UG.find({ "emailUser": req.body.emailUser }, "nameGroup -id" ,function (err, groups) {
    console.log(groups)
});
```

> For the _id field, you do not have to explicitly specify _id: 1 to
>   return the _id field. The find() method always returns the _id field
>   unless you specify _id: 0 to suppress the field.